# Stuck duplicate transaction in BitcoinQT

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, transaction-malleability

I received two payments with the following transaction:

https://blockchain.info/tx/12e487de6fd8d920446cd8663dc11977d185ceaa25b7c6f36921fb76e58875f0

On this transaction

1HT1vrdy2fegnVKaTE1rqsFzfPVDpiWYjf output receives 0.1341765 BTC and 19tj6SNnJqZqmDvMuhrjwPudX8qVcT392a output receives 0.27240743.

I have this transaction in my BitcoinQT client. It shows confirmed and everything is fine. The problem is that I have another transaction which has the same inputs and outputs with the above but a different TxID.

It has been stuck in my wallet unconfirmed for two weeks. BC.info does not show this transaction. Neither does any other online service. Below are the full details.

I have around 10 other transaction in my wallet like this. What is this?￼ Why is this happening?

```
gettransaction 98ea1e0d4169af104fe36535a4615ab82086750323ce4e539b7d9c82707955f6
{
"amount" : 0.40658393,
"confirmations" : 0,
"txid" : "98ea1e0d4169af104fe36535a4615ab82086750323ce4e539b7d9c82707955f6",
"time" : 1392119952,
"timereceived" : 1392119952,
"details" : [
{
"account" : "520c7bb149ede83218f46c96",
"address" : "1HT1vrdy2fegnVKaTE1rqsFzfPVDpiWYjf",
"category" : "receive",
"amount" : 0.13417650
},
{
"account" : "520c7bb149ede83218f46c96",
"address" : "19tj6SNnJqZqmDvMuhrjwPudX8qVcT392a",
"category" : "receive",
"amount" : 0.27240743
}
]
}

gettransaction 12e487de6fd8d920446cd8663dc11977d185ceaa25b7c6f36921fb76e58875f0
{
"amount" : 0.40658393,
"confirmations" : 2490,
"blockhash" : "00000000000000007465867d49096a642c424ae015691c0b0f6280c3bc6de401",
"blockindex" : 78,
"blocktime" : 1392120874,
"txid" : "12e487de6fd8d920446cd8663dc11977d185ceaa25b7c6f36921fb76e58875f0",
"time" : 1392120874,
"timereceived" : 1392120896,
"details" : [
{
"account" : "520c7bb149ede83218f46c96",
"address" : "1HT1vrdy2fegnVKaTE1rqsFzfPVDpiWYjf",
"category" : "receive",
"amount" : 0.13417650
},
{
"account" : "520c7bb149ede83218f46c96",
"address" : "19tj6SNnJqZqmDvMuhrjwPudX8qVcT392a",
"category" : "receive",
"amount" : 0.27240743
}
]
}
```

Comment: Have you read https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=35214.0?

Comment: @Jori Yes I did. But there is a difference between sending a transaction that does not get confirmed and having a duplicate of a confirmed transaction with a different ID stuck in your wallet. I want to find out how this happened.

Comment: @AntonAnsgar, Can you point us to your other transactions that are differing only in the TXID?

Comment: Hi! This is actually resolved with v0.9 of bitcoin core. These transaction were result of malleability and they are now showing as Conflicted on Bitcoin Core. You will probably not be able to observe them from another copy of the blockchain.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core (bitcoind and Bitcoin-Qt's new name) v0.9 will deal much better with these conflicting transactions within one wallet.

It will keep showing both, but the non-confirming one will be marked "conflicted" with -1 confirmations, will not be rebroadcasted, and won't be considered to have spendable outputs.

Comment: Good news! Thank you! My understanding is that these conflicts occurred because of malleability, can please you confirm? And where can I see the planned release date for v0.9? I looked everywhere and can't find it.

Comment: It looks like the result of malleability indeed. The release data for 0.9: "when it is ready". However, we already have a release candidate 2. Maybe it takes 1 or 2 more candidates.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm surprised this effect of malleability on Bitcoin Core isn't mentioned anywhere else. Except for Gavin Andresen's blog post which briefly mentions some coins might get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing `getrawtransaction txid` with txid of the offending transaction. Then, issue `sendrawtransaction string` with the string outputted by the first command. You can possibly post this string there, or try using it in another wallet software, this can give you some information on this TX and maybe finally broadcast it.

If you want to get rid of this TX, you can backup your wallet, remove all files from your ~/.bitcoin directory or its equivalent (the directory containing the blockchain), redownload the blockchain (possibly using the bootstrap.dat) and import your backupped keys back.

Comment: Already tried both. Tried broadcasting the Tx through both my wallet and blockchain.info. BC won't broadcast saying inputs have already been spent. Which is true. And nothing happens when I do the same from inside my Bitcoin client. Copied wallet and redownloaded blockchain, transactions are still there. I think the funds are stuck until a fix is released by core devs. Gavin's posts about malleability on foundation's blog says some transactions might be stuck and that they need to update the software to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

1. Dump all your private keys (`dumpprivkey`). Be sure to get all your receiving and change addresses. Back up wallet.dat just in case something bad happens.
2. Delete wallet.dat.
3. Open up bitcoin-qt again. It should create a new wallet.dat. Now go into the console and run `importprivkey` on each of those private keys.

Comment: I'm mainly trying to find out how and why this happened so that I can prevent it from happening again.