# How can I tell Bitcoin to only spend confirmed inputs and self created outputs

Tags: transactions, client

I want to make sure that the transactions I create with the original client are always using confirmed inputs and self created outputs.

Bitcoin used one of the transactions that I describe here in this question: [Stuck duplicate transaction in BitcoinQT](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/22663/stuck-duplicate-transaction-in-bitcoinqt)

as an input. So the new transaction is not being confirmed either.

I want to make sure that my transactions are always using confirmed transactions. Is this possible?

Comment: You can't use self-created outputs until they have sufficient confirmations. Otherwise, your transactions can fail to confirm due to signature malleability.

Comment: Hey David, thank you. Do you mean I shouldn't or I can't? Because like I said in the question, Bitcoin did use a self created transaction that has 0 confirmations as an input. Mind you that the both transactions are still unconfirmed. And I think they never will be. Because the input transaction is a duplicate of another transaction that did get confirmed. What I mean by duplicate is exactly the same inputs and outputs but different TXid.

Comment: Right, that's why you don't want to use even your own outputs until they have sufficient confirmations. You don't know what the transaction ID will be.